# Allocating memory for sprintf for char * and int

Tags: c, int, malloc

Sorry I'm a newb, and I'm struggling with this,

I want to first allocate enough memory to hold 3 strings plus an integer

```
char *final;
char string1[256];
char string2[256];
char string3[256];
int myNum, mySize= 0;

// populate values
...

mySize += strlen(string1) + strlen(string2) + strlen(string3);

final = malloc(mySize);

sprintf(final, "%s = %s{%s:%d}", string1, string2, string3, myNum);
```

The integer could be something as large as 90,000 so how do I know how much to allocate for the integer? Sorry, if it's simple,

I've just realized I need to allocate +1 for the null pointer, and for the =, {, etc. symbols

Thanks!

Comment: You could just count.  The extra punctuation takes 6 characters.  An int will take 10 characters at most if it is 32-bits.  One more for the zero terminator.  Add 256, a nice round number, if you don't want to be bitten by minor maintenance edits for a while.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. Do you want a string to be able to hold the numeric representation of some number up to 90,000?

Or are you trying to malloc an integer pointer?

Comment: @xyzjace I am trying to allocate the space that it would take for "90000" to be printed as a string (in this case it would be +5)

Comment: string1 ... string3 are all uninitalised. calling strlen() on them is asking for trouble. BTW: generally, snprintf() is the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are printing an integer value as a string.

Create another character array to hold the string-conversion of the integer, then sum.

Don't forget you need one more byte to hold the trailing NULL character, `'\0'`, to terminate a string. It would be a worthwhile exercise to read up on the difference between character arrays and strings (ie: strings are character arrays that end with `'\0'` at some point in the array).

```
char *final;
char string1[256];
char string2[256];
char string3[256];
char numberString[256];
int myNum, mySize= 0;

// populate values
...
sprintf(numberString,"%d",myNum);

mySize = strlen(string1) + strlen(string2) + strlen(string3) + strlen(numberString) + 1;

final = malloc(mySize*sizeof(char)); //The sizeof(char) is probably overkill, but safe practise

if(final) // check for null in case malloc failed above
{
  sprintf(final, "%s = %s{%s:%d}", string1, string2, string3, myNum);
} else {
  printf("MEMORY ERROR");
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is really overkill because it is always 1 in C and C++ languages (check standard)

Comment: No debate on that one. I generally do it for two key reasons though: 1) Best practise (so I don't get sloppy when working with other data types);  2) sizeof() is resolved at compile time, and not run time, so it doesn't add any bulk/overhead to my application.

Comment: Ok so I have been told by someone reviewing my code that the numberString in this example is unnecessary because when calculating "mySize" I can simply add `sizeof(int)`. I said ok and made the change since he's more experienced than myself. But I would be curious to know your reaction to this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The size of type integer is fixed in the byte sense, so don't worry about that unless your value can exceed the size of the maximum integer. You have a problem calling `strlen` on your arrays, as they are uninitialised and so `strlen` will be looking for a null terminating char which may or may not be set. If you want to allocate 256 bytes like this you would be better using `sizeof string1` rather than `strlen(string1)`. From what you say, it may be better to consider creating a struct with 3 `char[256]` arrays and an integer member for your needs and to deal with that as a non-dynamically allocated object. Your `char` arrays are already created in terms of space, so the `malloc` does nothing except allocate more space here. Are you sure this is what you want?